# How to calculate Time difference in Java?

Tags: java

Is there any way we can calculate the exact time difference between two times.

For. e.g.

```
t1= 11:18 
t2= 20:20
t2 - t1 = 9.02
```

I have tried this code but its not helping.

```
String hour1=h1+":"+m1;
String hour2= h2+":"+m2;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date d1= dateFormat.parse(hour1);
Date d2= dateFormat.parse(hour2);
long d=d2.getTime()-d1.getTime();
long hour= d/(60*60*1000) % 24;
```

By using this code the I am unable to find the Minutes difference.

Comment: Well you've got code to work out the hours... what have you *tried* for the minutes? (Hint: don't divide by 60 as many times...)

Comment: Wait, you have your times in `h1`:`m1` and `h2`:`m2` so why don't you use those value to do the math ?

Comment: well I tried and got the maths wrong at the first place @AxelH that's why switched to this format

Comment: Thanks 
I understood what you meant to say..!! long dmin = d / (60 * 1000) % 60;
Thanks again :)
@JonSkeet

Comment: @Saurabh you could have tried a bit more, yes there is some trick here since you need to substract one hour in some case. But you could simply convert the hour in minute to add that to the minute, do the math the recreate the hour:minute format.

Comment: Thanks @AxelH 
I'll try this way too. :)

Comment: thanks @jnbbender
I'll try your way too.. :)

Answer (score 2):

JDK 8 date time API greatly simplifies these, time differences can be calculated using Duration as below:

```
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.of(11, 18);
LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.of(20, 20);
System.out.println(Duration.between(t1, t2)); //output - PT9H2M
```

The output is 9 Hours and 2 Minutes. ( 9H 2M)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to convert to a different time zone and check the difference in time. You could grab the time in milliseconds and compare the values like I did below for your case. Just subtract timeInMillisTwo from timeInMillisOne.

```
Date date = dateFormat.parse("");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // that is NOW for the timezone configured on the computer.

long timeInMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis(); 
cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis + (60000 * 60 * 5) - (60000 * 15));
//the line above converts to a different time zone and subtracts fifteen 
//minutes. 
long fifteenMinutesAgo = cal.getTime();

if(date.after(fifteenMinutesAgo)){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work.

```
package cn.sz.cyrus.java8test;

public class TimeCalcute {

    public static String calcTime(String time1, String time2) {
        String[] times1 = time1.split(":");
        String[] times2 = time2.split(":");
        int timeint1 = Integer.valueOf(times1[0]) * 60 + Integer.valueOf(times1[1]);
        int timeint2 = Integer.valueOf(times2[0]) * 60 + Integer.valueOf(times2[1]);
        int interval = timeint1 - timeint2;
        String result = String.format("%d:%02d", interval / 60, interval % 60);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String time1 = "20:20";
        String time2 = "11:18";
        System.out.println(calcTime(time1, time2));
        time1 = "22:46";
        time2 = "10:59";
        System.out.println(calcTime(time1, time2));
    }

}
```

This is print result :

9:02

11:47

Answer (score 1):

You can get the difference between two dates as millisecondes, then you can convert it to minutes or hours,

```
public static Long getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        long diffInMillies = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
        return diffInMillies;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double value=  Test.getDateDiff( new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+37*10000),  new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    System.out.println("Hour:"+value/(100*60*60));
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.  To calculate minutes you just needed.

```
long minutes = d / (60*1000) % 60;
long seconds = d / 1000 % 60;
```

I added the seconds just in case.  Although I did kind of like @Pallavi's answer, using Duration, it was a little more contrived pulling the actual data from the resulting object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JodaTime if you are not using JDK 8, but with JDK 8 you can write something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 2, 5, 11, 18, 0);
    LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 2, 5, 20, 20, 0);

    long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(from, to);
    System.out.println(String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60)));
}
```

The output will be: 9:02:00

To get the difference between two *LocalDateTime* you could use the *Duration* class, but there is no formatter for the it in JDK 8, so if you need this specific output format then you will either use a 3rd party library or write your own formatter like the one above in the example.

To use a Duration you can write:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 2, 5, 11, 18, 0);  
    LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 2, 5, 20, 20, 0);

    Duration duration = Duration.between(from, to);

    long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
    System.out.println(String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", s / 3600, (s % 3600) / 60, (s % 60))); 
}
```

Cheers, A.